# How to create a trigger that checks if Likes(B,C) exists when Likes(A,B) is inserted and then insert a tuple Likes(A,C)? Transitive Likes should work

Tags: sqlite, triggers

table details are:

Likes ( ID1, ID2 )

Comment: How does it know what C is? And which database are you using, MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: sqlite. Please tell the approach how you would do it.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're trying to do is this...

- A likes B.
- B likes C.
- Therefore A likes C.

Hard coding "A likes C" into the table is fragile. Consider what happens if B stops liking C. Do you delete "A likes C"? How do you know it was transitive? What if A said they like C? You can get around this with a column that says "A likes C" was transitive.

What you have here is a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)). And what you're asking is every time you add or delete an edge to check whether this changes the connection between ALL nodes. That is an extraordinarily expensive thing to do. Consider this.

```
A -> B -> C

X -> Y -> Z
```

So it's inferred that A likes C and X likes Z.

What if C likes X? Now...

- A likes X
- A likes Y
- A likes Z
- B likes X
- B likes Y
- B likes Z
- C likes Y
- C likes Z

Now what if B unlikes C?

- A unlikes C
- A unlikes X
- A unlikes Y
- A unlikes Z
- B unlikes X
- B unlikes Y
- B unlikes Z

And that's a simple linear case with just six nodes.

Hard coding every possible relationship in a graph is a bad idea. And SQL databases aren't very good at traversing graphs.

Instead you want to store and walk the graph. This is probably not possible with SQLite's limited query language. You can use a [graph database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) or the [WITH query in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).